# Can a c++ class own subclasses

Tags: c++

Lets say you have the class `a` and you want to add a child class `b` how would you go by doing this? Maybe something like this:

```cpp
class a{
   public:
      class b{
      };
};
```

Maybe it did make the class but as its clasified as an obj how would you make one. Like if you were to implement a as an object in your code it would look something like this:

```cpp
a myObj;
```

But what about implementing b from a?

Comment: If by "implement" you mean "create an instance of" then you'd use `a::b` as the type of the variable

Comment: Have a look at nested classes: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types.

Comment: You just define a type `b` as a "child" type of type `a`. That doesn't mean that any object of type `a` will contain a subobject of type `b`. Is this what you want to achieve? It's not clear to me from your description. Or, do you just want to create an object of type `a::b`?

Comment: Thank you so much everybody for the help. I am new to c++ and so i was a little confused when i tried to emplement a class inside a class and it didn't quite work out. Again tysm!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can

Lets take the following example:

```
/// define the outer struct
struct Outer{
    /// Define the inner struct
    struct Inner {};

    /// Up to this point, Outer has NOTHING in it, only a definition for
    ///     Inner without any objects.
    
    /// And now inside Outer you can use Inner struct for anything you want.
    /// For example Outer can have (but not required) a member called data of 
    ///     type Inner like:
    Inner data;
};

/// Now we create an object of type Outer:
Outer a;
/// Now a has a member called data of type Outer::Inner
/// Note in global scope Inner is undefined, you don't have Inner,
///     only Outer::Inner!!
/// But if Inner is public (i have used struct so it is) you can create 
///     Outer::Inner objects:
Outer::Inner b;
/// Now b is an object of type Outer::Inner
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: inside class `a`: `b obj`. outside the class `a::b obj`

I think you don't quite understand what instantiation and implementation mean.

When you IMPLEMENT (or rather, in this case, EXTEND) a class, you create a SUBCLASS.

When you INSTANTIATE a class (call its ctor or `new`), you create an INSTANCE, an OBJECT.

So, if your question is whether you can extend an inner class, the answer is yes, of course you can: classes are, at their core, just namespaces. So, you can create another class in the namespace `a` that extends the class `a::b`.
Example:

```
class a {
public:
   class b {
      virtual void printsomething() { printf("This is the original\n"); }
   };
   
   class c: b {
      virtual void printsomething() override { printf("This is the new\n"); }
   }
};
```

If your question was whether you can instantiate an inner class, then the answer is still yes. As before, classes are just namespaces. So you can do something like this:

```
class a {
   class b {
      void printsomething() { printf("PRINTING...\n"); }
   };
   
   void dosomething() {
      b obj;
      obj.printsomething();
   }
};
```

In either case, you can also instantiate the inner classes from outside class `a` like so:

```
int main() {
   a::b obj1;
   obj1.printsomething();
   a::c obj2;
   obj2.printsomething();
}
```

Comment: Too much Java terminology here. <g> In C++ we **derive** from a  class; we don't "extend" it. And we have **nested** classes, not "inner" classes. (Inner class means something magical in Java; there is no counterpart in C++)